# How to set published status to a static value while importing a CSV using Feeds

Tags: feeds

How can I set the published status of a node created by Feeds to unpublished for every node it imports?

I am using a manually uploaded CSV file.

Comment: I just found out that if I set the default settings on the content type to unpublished it won't publish it, but this isn't the exact behavior I want.

Answer (score 3):

Add a new column to your CSV, fill it with 0, and import that as Published Status.